# Run make command in Jenkins

Tags: c++, ubuntu, jenkins, makefile

I'm trying to build c++ project.

When I run the make command in terminal it works,
but when I do it through Jenkins, it shows me a message that files are missing.

What can be the problem, and how can I solve it?

**The Error:**

```
+ make
make -f enclave_lib.mk SGX_DEBUG=1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yoni/Documents/private_ledger-tp/CryptoLib'
mt19937ar.c:44:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You should at least share the error messages.

Comment: @Jodocus I added, I didn't think it is useful. As it's a c++ error that doesn't happened when I run make from Terminal

Comment: Does your build slave have `stdio.h`?  What debugging steps have you tried so far?

Comment: @StephenNewell - not sure, I'm handling the Jenkins not the project itself. I only know the make file runs fine on same location, when I use the Terminal instead of Jenkins

Comment: When you log yourself with Jenkins credentials, and you go on Jenkins' workspace, are you able to reproduce this error?

Comment: @Luc not sure what you mean by login with Jenkins credentials

Comment: For example, if you run "whoami" instead of "make", is the user returned yourself or another user?

Comment: @Luc it returns 'root' which is not myself

Comment: Running Jenkins as root sounds like a large security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, the problem is that Jenkins is executed as root user, and can not find the lib stdio.h.

To fix this you can have several options:

- locate stdio.h
  You run this command from your user. It will give you the path to stdio.h. That you can feed in your make
- sudo apt-get install build-essential

As a root user, you install build-essential. That should install this missing dependency

- execute Jenkins with your privilege, not with root privilege
- in your build process, connect to your account (su youruser)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that in our case it was an issue of environment variables.

What I did to solve it is

1. Getting the data on environment variables both from Terminal and Jenkins, and write them sorted into 2  files.
2. Comparing the 2 files with meld
3. Any variables that seemed relevant that the Terminal environment and the Jenkins didn't I placed into /etc/environment file (Jenkins takes additional environment vars from there)

   env | sort > envInTerminal.txt

   env | sort > envInJenkins.txt

   meld envInTerminal.txt envInJenkins.txt

   sudo gedit /etc/environment